# create img with onerror attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am creating some images in my page. When I write `<img src=somesrc, onerror=othersrc></img>`, it works fine.

But when I create image using jQuery it fails:

```
jQuery('<img />', {
    onerror: "javascript: this.src='some_default_image_source'", 
    src: 'image_source'}).appendTo("#container");
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: *But when I create image using jQuery it fails* How does it fail? What exactly fails?

Comment: @FelixKling the **onerror** code does not get executed and so the default image does not get loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jQuery('<img />').error(function() {
    this.src = 'some_default_image_source';
}).attr('src', 'image_source').appendTo("#container");
```

Comment: does not work in jq 1.5 but changed to `.error` and works fine. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Works fine. [Link to jsFiddle plus extra words](http://jsfiddle.net/EFGrR/4/)

Comment: Always a good idea to specify if you are using an older version of a library and not providing a demo/link.

Comment: I want to make this event useful for future img elements also. So I use `$(document).on('error',"img",function () {` instead of `$('img').on('error',function() {` but now it is not working . any solutions??

Comment: Image errors don't bubble up to the `document` [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) So you'll need to bind an error handler to each new image you dynamically add.